# Allegro library with Code Blocks mac osx

Tags: macos, codeblocks, allegro

spent some time, with the big help of other SO user, trying to install Allegro library on osx 10.10.5
Finally it seems like it is ok, so I open the code blocks, pasted the example code( http://partitionseven.blogspot.com/2011/01/compiling-allegro-5-with-mac-os-x-snow.html), and I get an error while copiling

```
g++   -c /Users/lukasz/Desktop/test_allegro/test.cpp -o /Users/lukasz/Desktop/test_allegro/test.o
g++  -o /Users/lukasz/Desktop/test_allegro/test /Users/lukasz/Desktop/test_allegro/test.o   
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_al_clear_to_color", referenced from:
      __al_mangled_main in test.o
  "_al_create_display", referenced from:
      __al_mangled_main in test.o
  "_al_destroy_display", referenced from:
      __al_mangled_main in test.o
  "_al_flip_display", referenced from:
      __al_mangled_main in test.o
  "_al_install_system", referenced from:
      __al_mangled_main in test.o
  "_al_map_rgb", referenced from:
      __al_mangled_main in test.o
  "_al_rest", referenced from:
      __al_mangled_main in test.o
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
     (maybe you meant: __al_mangled_main)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

when I follow the tutorial exactly running the code from terminal with

```
gcc alleg5test.c -o alleg5test -L/usr/local/lib -lallegro -lallegro_main
./alleg5test
```

it works- i got a black screen. But how do I make it work from Code Blocks?